# DateTime.Parse different on XP vs Windows 7 / 8

Tags: .net, windows, parsing, date, datetime

Doing the following on XP and Windows 7 yields different results in a .NET4 vs. a .NET2 console application:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("DateTime.Parse on Client: {0}", 
   DateTime.Parse("1998-10-31T00:00:00-04:00")));
```

.NET4
**Under XP this returns:** 10/31/1998 12:00:00 AM
**Under Windows 7/Windows 8 this returns:** 10/30/1998 11:00:00 PM

.NET2
**Under XP this returns:** 10/31/1998 12:00:00 AM
**Under Windows 7/Windows 8 this returns:** 10/31/1998 12:00:00 AM

WHY??!?

Removing the TimeZone (the -04:00) from the string causes the value to be the same on both XP and Windows 7 under .NET4. It appears that Windows XP applies the timezone offset differently under .NET4 when doing a DateTime.Parse from the string. Is there some way to change this behavior so that it is consistent under .NET4, reguardless of OS (that does not involve manipulating the string being sent into DateTime.Parse)

**Environment:**
All machines have the latest patches installed (available via Windows Update) and are configured to Eastern Time with the 'Automatically adjust clock for Daylight Savings Time' checked in the 'Time Zone Settings'.

I have confirmed this behavior on both a Windows 7 machine with .NET4 and a Windows 7 machine with .NET4.5

Comment: can you please post the relevant piece of XML showing the date string?. Also, do ALL machines have the latest service packs? the DST info is shipped (not all the time) with service packs.

Comment: I recommend you experiment with a simpler service to narrow down the problem. Try a service call that just returns a `DateTime`. This will eliminate `DataSet` from the problem.

Comment: @JohnSaunders The DateTime operation is correct in all environments.  I have updated the post to include the new operation and the results.

Comment: @wal all machines are indeed patched (at least according to what Windows Update displays).

Comment: Then it would seem that your problem is with `DataSet`, which is never a good idea to return from a service.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I agree with you; however, the question is how do I work around the issue and why is it doing what it is doing.  The DataSet exposes a column of DateTime which is no different than the DateTime type exposed by the service operation GetDateTime().  Why is the serializer treating the type differently when it is exposed by the DataSet and including the timezone offset, where as it is not including this offset when serializing the native type as returned by a service operation -- and most importantly, why is this NOT HAPPENING under Windows XP.

Comment: This is no doubt a bug in the XmlSerializer on Windows XP. However, since Windows XP is unsupported, and since the XmlSerializer is only taking the most business-critical bugs, I doubt that it will be addressed.

Comment: Note that `DataSet` is probably using the XML Serializer, whereas your simple `DateTime` example was probably using the `DataContractSerializer`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders My understanding was the default WCF serializer is the DataContractSerializer, unless you over-ride the method or class with the [XmlSerializerFormat] attribute.  I have done this and the resultant  XML visable via Fiddler looks the same.

Comment: @Art now that you have the string that was sent over the wire, what happens on the client machines (both XP and Win7 when you try `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse("1998-10-31T00:00:00-04:00"))` ??

Comment: I mean that `DataSet` is special. In fact, it's so special, that you shouldn't be using it!

Comment: @wal this was a great idea!  The results are different (see question above).  This has nothing to do with the DataSet, but how .NET is parsing the DateTime string under Windows XP vs. Windows 7.  Now -- the question is, how do I fix it :)

Comment: I recommend that you delete this question and start a new one, leaving out the web services and serialization aspect.

Comment: What happens if you remove the timezone from the date string?

Comment: @JohnSaunders removing the TimeZone (the -04:00) from the string causes the value to be the same on both XP and Windows 7.  It appears that Windows XP does not apply the timezone offset when doing a DateTime.Parse from the string. Is there some way to change this behavior so that it is consistent, reguardless of OS?

Comment: Sure. Write your own method, and check the OS you're running. Why do you need to parse strings, though? Or if you have to parse something, convert the DateTime to UTC and parse that.

Comment: I think this is a rather interesting question, so I cleaned it up to be more on-topic. Also, do you have .Net 4 or .Net 4.5 on Windows 7/8? 4.5 is an in-place upgrade, so it can sometimes hide as 4..

Comment: Good point @Earlz My Windows 7/8 machines both have .NET 4.5. I will spin up a Windows 7 VM with just .NET4 and update the question with the results.The XP machine has just .NET4

Comment: Art can you confirm all machines (W7 and XP) are on EST (-5)? I think @Earlz removed this important information.
If yes, i've tried on my VM's here and I get 11pm for both

Comment: I @wal re-added the time zone detail and confirmed.  Did you test the same date I am using and under .NET4?  The problem appears to be date specific.  10/31/1998 is the day of daylight savings time.  What VMs OS did you try it on -- XP and 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calculating the local time for historical dates requires .NET knowing the daylight savings time rules that were in effect during that date.  That's of course a pretty tricky thing to do since DST rules vary a great deal across localities and dates.

Your date has a UTC offset of -4 which puts it somewhere close to the Eastern timezone in the USA.  The most relevant DST rule change there was the 2005 Energy Policy Act which extended the period that DST is in effect from the 2nd Sunday in March to the 1st Sunday in November, effective in 2007.  So knowing the local time in October 31st, 1998 requires knowing that this law was not yet in effect.

And that's where the difference comes from.  Windows Vista was the first Windows version that has a database of these DST changes, .NET 4 was the first .NET version that started using it.  XP doesn't have that database so .NET cannot do anything but assume that current DST rules are in effect.

This is the inevitable lossage you need to deal with when working with local time.  Don't, use UTC.

Comment: I am assuming this is also true for operating systems derived from the Windows XP core, such as Windows Server 2003? Can I somehow force .NET4 running under configurations more modern than XP to not use this database and give me the wrong time? I'd rather be consistently wrong than right some of the time.

Comment: In summary: The Windows XP machine is giving an incorrect time.  Emulating that behavior would be wrong. :)

Comment: As I said, use UTC instead.  You'll be consistently wrong the right way.

Answer (score 1):

A `DateTime` value can't represent any arbitrary offset.  It only tracks a `.Kind` property, which can be `UTC`, `Local`, or `Unspecified`.

When you parse a string *without* an offset into a `DateTime`, the kind will be `Unspecified`.

When you parse a string *with* an offset into a `DateTime`, the kind will be `Local` and then the time will be adjusted base on the offset you provided *and* the offset determined from your local time zone.

So `1998-10-31T00:00:00-04:00` is first converted to UTC `1998-10-30T20:00:00-00:00` and then the local computer's offset (in your case, Eastern Daylight Time -05:00) is applied and you get a Local time of `1998-10-30T23:00:00-05:00`.

As Hans explained in his answer, neither .Net 2.0 nor Windows XP can properly distinguish daylight savings time differences within the same time zone.  So you would always get back -04:00 for eastern, regardless of which date it was for.

The best way to avoid all of this nonsense is to use a `DateTimeOffset` type instead.  It will track the offset you originally gave it, and you can convert it where necessary.  It exists in .Net 2.0 with SP1, but under .Net 3.5+ (incl 4.0) you can also use the `TimeZoneInfo` class to easily manipulate it.

So change your code to `DateTimeOffset.Parse("1998-10-31T00:00:00-04:00")` and you will be in much better shape.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like one machine has daylight savings time checked in its environment settings and the other does not.

Comment: As I mentioned (and to clarity): clients and server are reporting the same time, are set to the same time zone, and both set to 'Automatically Adjust for Daylight Savings Time'.  If there is some other setting I need to check, please clarify.  The only difference between the two clients is the OS.

Comment: As wal suggests, make sure both systems are fully patched.

Comment: All system are fully patched (just ran Windows Update on them).

Comment: Check out this blog post: http://tadams1138.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-solve-datasets-change-datetime.html

Comment: That article deals with DataSets spanning timezones;  in my example, the timezone of the server and the clients are the same.  Checking the column's DateTimeMode on the two different client machines and the server machine results in 'UnspecifiedLocal'.  There should be no issue with time zone adjustment here.